# Can we have a compartment other than Patient in FHIR?

Tags: hl7-fhir

FHIR docs say:
`Each resource may belong to one or more logical compartments` [here](http://hl7.org/fhir/extras.html#compartment)

On the other hand, it also says that the specs define `patient` as a compartment. Does that mean we can only have patient as a compartment or can we have any resource to define a compartment?

eg. `organization/{organizationID}/device/{deviceID}`

Also, can we have some other noun in the REST call other than the resource name, although we will be exchanging FHIR valid JSON?

eg. instead of `organization`, we use `facility` (above example) but still exchange the organization resource in JSON.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a specific set of resources that have been defined as usable for compartments.  They are listed here: http://hl7-fhir.github.io/extras.html.  If you feel you need compartments for an additional resource, you can make a proposal.

The names of end points in FHIR are fixed for interoperability purposes.  I.e. everyone needs to use "organization" rather than "facility", though this has no impact on how systems choose to expose information within a user interface.  I.e. Even if the API interfaces says "organization", an EHR user interface can use the term "facility" if that makes more sense based on the context.

Comment: Hmm, then why do we have conflicting statements in the docs? Also, the latest doc is http://hl7.org/fhir/extras.html#compartment which defines compartment for only 1 resource type.

Comment: The latest doc is not at hl7.org/fhir.  That's the DSTU 1 official version.  In DSTU 1, only the Patient compartment exists.  The link I provided takes you to the current draft of DSTU 2 (slated for official publication sometime this September).  It permits several additional compartments.  If you find conflicting documentation within the draft DSTU2 version of the specification, let us know.